How to mock gorqlite database connection ? and Daoer interface?
    // rqliteDao implements the Daoer interface for interacting with an rqlite database.
    type rqliteDao struct {
        conn *gorqlite.Connection
    }

    // NewRQLiteDao creates a new instance of rqliteDao.
    func NewRQLiteDao() (Daoer, error) {
        // Connect to rqlite cluster
        conn, err := gorqlite.Open(os.Getenv("RQLITE_DB"))
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        return &rqliteDao{
            conn: conn,
        }, nil
    }

This is my original connection to connect to rqlite db.
How do I mock this connection to use something like this
    // mock the database 
    // Create a new rqliteDao instance with the mock connection
    dao := &rqliteDao{conn: mockConn}

and run the functionality tests like dao.functions
mocking is not working

Personally haven't worked with this database, so can't be 100% sure. But, perhaps testcontainers could help you here? You wouldn't need to mock it, rather just spin up a testcontainer and connect to it. Use it like you would in production.
